# React redux not overiding similar object in an array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reduce

React redux not overiding similar object in an array.
[image]

I was expecting arrray of object with different properties. Also If there was any similar property in array than the count will increase from 1 to onwards

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) You're directly modifying state when you push into `ShopItems` or increment the quantity.

Comment: The "CARTITEMS" case doesn't return a state. Is it intentional?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.push` doesn't create array and you should avoid using it.
And you're not returning new state for **Case CARTITEMS**
you should always return a new state for each case clause.
Also try to split **CARTITEMS** case clause into 2 different actions, one to increase the quantity and one for adding new item but remember to avoid **Array.push()** and instead

```
return {...state, newPropToOverride }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the question is

```
case ADDCARTITEMS:
      // adding items to cart and removing duplicates while counting them
      const isItem = state.CartItems.find(ci => ci.id === action.payload.id)
      if(isItem){
        return {
          ...state,
          CartItems: state.CartItems.map(item => {
          if(item.id === action.payload.id){
            return {...item, count: item.count + 1}
          } else {
            return item
          }
          })
        }
      }
      else { 
        return {
          ...state,
          CartItems: [...state.CartItems, {...action.payload, count: 1}]
        }
      }
```